# Round image as background for input type="submit"

Tags: forms

In the page found in below link(bg-button.html), I have put round image as a background using styles. But I find a gray background outside the image area. How can I make the background transparent, Please let me know?
[Round image as background](http://shivanand.in/temp/bg-button.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following style to the button:

```
background-color: transparent;
```

Alternatively, use `#fff`.

Answer (score 1):

You must edit the image in a paint program (like [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)), add a transparency layer, remove the part you don't like with the eraser and save it as GIF or PNG.

Note that IE 6 doesn't handle PNG transparency without [some tricks](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6).

Answer (score 0):

Going off what the above poster said, you can generally get around this without thinking about it by just using shorthand, ala:

div#example { background: transparent url("imgurl.png") no-repeat top left; }

Comment: Using the shorthand does not require "transparent", as it is the default value. This would achieve the same effect: background: url("imgurl.png") no-repeat 0 0;

Comment: Yeah, I know. My comment was moreso towards building a pattern so you never have to think about it, it's automatic. ;)